# Would disabling all Application Layer Gateway settings increase security?

Tags: router, sip

I was looking for ways to harden the security on my TP-Link router and found the ALG (Application Layer Gateway) settings under the security section.

I have disabled the following:

PPTP Pass-through

L2TP Pass-through

IPSec-Pass-through

FTP ALG

TFPT ALG

H323 ALG

SIP ALG

I think most (if not all?) TP-Link routers have these but I'm not sure if disabling/enabling them would make a difference.
Would disabling these enhance the security of my home network, or could it even be the other way around?

So far everything seems to work without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

These settings are used to let specific complex protocol traverse the router. If you don't use these protocols it is useful to disable the functionality since it adds unnecessary complexity and might even aid in bypassing firewall settings like in [the slipstream attack](https://samy.pl/slipstream/).

Comment: Thank you Steffen! So disabling these will actually increase the security of my router/home network?

Comment: @CassieB_1booi: disabling will not weaken the security. It might increase the security or not, depending on how robust and secure these implementations are. But in general more complexity (i.e. enabling these ALG) weakens security.

Comment: Thank you so much for clearing that up! I will keep these disabled then. It's a bit weird though that the TP-Link settings page says the following: "It's recommended to leave these as default" since they're all enabled by default.

Comment: @CassieB_1booi: these ALG serve a purpose - allowing complex protocols traverse the router. Thus disabling these protocols might impact functionality - a classic is that active FTP does not work. Thus if you see a router primarily as a device to provide functionality it makes sense to have these options enabled by default. If you see it instead as a security boundary then not.